# Very slow subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, database-performance, sqlperformance

I have two tables A and B (names are abstracted). Both table A and table B have a column called date. Table A has about 3 million rows, with column date indexed. Table B has about 1 million rows.

I have the following query running very slowly (about 20 seconds):

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.date > (select MAX(date) FROM B)`

However, if I run the subquery separately first, it's very fast. And if I substitute the date into the main query, it's also super fast as the data in table A is indexed.

I have seen that this could be an issue if "IN" clause is used. But my query doesn't use IN. Can someone help explain why this is slow?

Thank you!

Comment: you are selecting every column from `A` which includes `non-index`ed columns.

Comment: @vkp in this case the select with a constant date should also be slow.

Comment: If you run the same query twice, does it speed up the second time?

Answer (score 2):

Move your subquery into the from clause as a derived table and join it to table A without a join condition:

```
SELECT * FROM A, (select MAX(date) AS mdate FROM B) AS T WHERE A.date > T.mdate
```

This way you can be sure that the subquery is calculated only once. If A.date is indexed as you wrote, this should speed-up your query. In the current form, I believe the subquery is executed for each record separately.

Comment: Shadow, unfortunately, this query is slow too, taking about 20 seconds. However, it only takes half a second if I substitute the time without the subquery.

Comment: Is the query cache enabled on the mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

How many time take `select MAX(date) AS mdate FROM B` alone?

You can probably save a lot of second if you have an index in **B**.date too